# Gradle jacoco multi project. How to output the code coverage of all the project in the terminal?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, gitlab, jacoco

I am using `Gradle jacoco` plugin and have `JUnit` tests in a gradle multi project.

I have installed jacoco in order to report to sonarqube my code coverage, which I did.

Gitlab-CI also offer a badge for the code coverage, I only need to output the code coverage in a terminal and use a regex to find it.

Is there a way to output the code coverage of all the project in the terminal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** Possible ways:

**1)** Use Gradle plugin [gradle-console-reporter](https://github.com/ksoichiro/gradle-console-reporter) to report various kinds of summaries to console. JUnit, JaCoCo and Cobertura reports are supported.

In your case, following output will be printed to console:

```
 ...
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL

 Total time: 4.912 secs

 Coverage summary:
 project1:                72.2%
 project2-with-long-name: 44.4%
```

Then you can use [coverage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#coverage) with regular expression in Gitlab's `.gitlab-ci.yml` to parse code coverage.

**2)** Second option is a little bit tricky. You can print full JaCoCo HTML report (e.g. using `cat target/site/jacoco/index.html`) and then use regular expression (see [this post](https://medium.com/@kaiwinter/javafx-and-code-coverage-on-gitlab-ci-29c690e03fd6)) or `grep` (see [this post](https://blog.exxeta.com/java/2018/08/12/display-the-test-coverage-with-gitlab/)) to parse coverage.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Gradle does not support this, each project is treated separately.

To support your use case some aggregation task can be created to parse a report and to update some value at root project and finally print that value to stdout.

**Update with approximate code for solution:**

```
subprojects {
    task aggregateCoverage {
        // parse report from each module into ext.currentCoverage 
        rootProject.ext.coverage += currentCoverage
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @webdizz I have tried to look at my jacoco file report and I can't figure out which one is the code coverage.

Comment: Jacoco provides several formats for report like csv, xml, html and binary. Please take a look at this link with documentation on Gradle Jacoco plugin https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html.